# ng-repeat not updating when ng-model input updates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Below I have code example that will successfully group data based on a model property for an ng-repeat, but only on the initial page load. So for example on load I do
`$scope.filter_items.group_1 = 'propb';` , which correctly repeats and groups by propb. Same if I switch it to `propa`.

The problem is that after the page loads, changing the `filter_items` model via an input has no effect on he ng-repeat, which doesn't update.  I've tried to work a bit with the .$apply() method, but nothing that worked (and from what I read I shouldn't have to use it). How can I get the ng-repeat to redraw after a model input change?

Note: I use the memoize function to avoid Angular digest errors, which will happen without it.

http://plnkr.co/N41D2Y

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.0" data-require="angular.js@*"></script>
    <script data-require="underscore.js@*" data-semver="1.6.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

      app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.filter_items = {};
        $scope.filter_items.group_1 = 'propb';
        $scope.items = [{id:"1", propa:"one", propb:"uno"},{id:"2", propa:"one", propb:"tres"}]
        return 
      });

      app.filter('myFilter', function() {
          return _.memoize(function(items, filter_items) {
                  return _.groupBy(items, filter_items.group_1);
              }
          );
      });      
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

      Group by<br>
        <select ng-model="filter_items.group_1">
                <option value="propa">A</option>
                <option value="propb">B</option>
        </select>

      <div ng-repeat="(group1, g_items) in items| myFilter:filter_items">
            <h2>{{group1}}</h2>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get your code working or then there's just something I don't understand or missed. But if custom filter is giving you headache, why don't you just put simple grouping function inside your controller?

Say, your controller

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    id:1, 
    propa:"one", 
    propb:"uno"
  },{
    id:2, 
    propa:"one", 
    propb:"uno"
  },{
    id:3, 
    propa:"two", 
    propb:"dos"
  },{
    id:4, 
    propa:"two", 
    propb:"dos"
  }];

  $scope.notGrouped = angular.copy($scope.items);
  $scope.options = ['propa','propb'];

  $scope.groupBy = function (option) {
    $scope.items = _.groupBy($scope.notGrouped, option);
  }
});
```

and related HTML template

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Group by<br>
    <select ng-model="selectedOption" 
            ng-options="option as option for option in options"
            ng-change="groupBy(selectedOption)">
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <div ng-hide="!!selectedOption">Not grouped yet...</div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <span>{{ item | json }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Would give you

[image: imgur]